# Node.js problem with downloading file - filename

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem, I made a Node.js server, and when I wanted to download a file from it, the file at the end of the name gets `_}`. I don't know why is that. Example  `img.jpg_}`

```
else if(req.url == '/download'){
var files = fs.createReadStream("img.jpg");
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=img.jpg"}'}); 
files.pipe(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey your quotes are misplaced.
use the following code it will work.

```js
else if(req.url == '/download'){
var files = fs.createReadStream("img.jpg");
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename = img.jpg'}); 
files.pipe(res);
```

Comment: Small complaint: I don't believe in adding extra unnecessary changes to code, since it might confuse OP. You've changed the single quotes to double quotes, which might conceivably make some people think single quotes are wrong.

Comment: @DavidKnipe
I just did that without thinking that, Don't worry I will edit it right away.

I hope now it is fine with you <3